# SBS 2003 to 2011 Migration: Public Folder Migration

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2003, windows-sbs-2011, migration

Been banging my head into this wall for a while now, but still can't seem to get past it.  Currently I'm trying to complete a migration from SBS 2003 to 2011.  I've been following along the Microsoft migration guide (except Sharepoint) to the letter with only a couple hangups.

Initially the SBS2003 mailstore would crash during migration; we installed Fix226580 from MS to resolve this issue.  Afterwards only a single mailbox would not transfer.  We deleted this as the user was no longer part of the company.  Now the only issue left is when I try to "Move All Replicas" of the Public folders.  I'm not receiving any crash notices, and the service "MSExchangeIS Public Store" is not throwing any errors. What I do see:

(SBS 2003, Exchange Version 6.5 Build 7638.2: SP2)

EventID 1205: MSExchange IS Mailbox Store - Failed to create mailbox with error 0x50c (I expect this is normal during mid-migration)

EventID 3017: NSExchangeIS Public Store - Outgoing message type 0x20 (I don't see any 0x40 messages for content replication.  I did only turn on error reporting when I started having issues, so I guess they might've occurred during original move request).

(SBS 2011, Exchange 2010 Version 14.1 Build 218.15)

EventID 1020: MSExchange Store Driver - The store driver couldn't deliver the public folder replication message "Folder Content Backfill Response (-IS@.ca)" because the following error occurred: The message content has become corrupted.. (Only received twice so far, last instance was from last weekend when I wasn't actively working on the issue).

EventID 3027: MSExchangeIS Public Store - Incoming replication message was processed Type: 0x20.

It could well be that all data has already synced fine (Where would I check this?  Under Org config -> Mailboxes, I see the public folders db but it lists no copies... ), and I'm stubbornly trying to get the replicas to no longer show up in the SBS2003 ESM.

It looks like communication between the servers is fine, and other than this move issue the setup has been running solid over the last couple weeks.  I'm relatively new at working with the guts of Exchange, so I'll be looking into other solutions on the side, but I was wondering if anyone has seen similar issues and may be able to point me in the right direction.  Thanks for any suggestions you can give me.

Comment: The "Message content has become corrupted" is still occurring on and off, it happens after a 0x80 request from my old Exchange 2003 is sent to the new server.  

It looks like I probably won't get any answers for this question, but I'll update this once I figure out the issue.

Comment: Update for anyone running into this kind of issue in the future.  Disabling Trend Micro on both servers and a couple updates/restarts later on our destination server seemed to fix up the EventID 1020 errors.

Some checking later, this doesn't seem to be a problem.  It looks like we're replicating now, but Folder Instances aren't moving

I also started noticing errors coming up on the source server saying the MDB Store had crashed and started to received MSExchangeIS Public Store Event: 3093 errors (public folder store object may not have been stamped with the correct ProxyAddresses attribute.)

Comment: Cut off my message.  Anyways, the 3093 errors don't seem to be causing any issues.  It looks like we're replicating now, but the Public Folder Instances still aren't budging on the source server.  Once I figure out all of this I'll make an answer that lists the resources I used/found helpful.  Actually if anyone knows, do the Public Folder Instances need to be migrated before I remove the old server, or will the existing replication in the new Public Folder be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally got around to this question again.  Essentially we called in Microsoft to help.  They didn't fix anything and just had us recreate the public folders that were having the issue on the new server.

In the end, that created a new mailbox that broke and caused us to have to manually uninstall the old Exchange server.  Definitely wasn't the smoothest migration, but it got done.

Closing ticket.